# Why is this tuple to tuple-of-references (std::tie) conversion valid?

Tags: c++, c++17, stdtuple

I'm in the process of making a class "std::tie-able". 
The class serves as a temporary object that fetches values depending on the type it's assigned to.

This is obvious to implement for assignment to a tuple:

```
// temporary class conversion operator
template<typename... T>
operator std::tuple<T...>() {
    return fetch_values<T...>(); // returns tuple<T...>
}
// usage:
std::tuple<int, int> = get_temporary();
```

However the class is supposed to be able to be used with std::tie as well.

```
int a, b;
std::tie(a, b) = get_temporary();
```

fetch_values expects value type arguments, so the above needs changes since tie results in T... being reference types. To achieve this I've ended up with an additional method for conversion to tuple-of-references:

```
template<typename... T>
operator std::tuple<T&...>() {
    auto result = fetch_values<T...>(); // returns tuple<T...>
    return result;
}
```

This does compile and work, but I have a couple of questions:

- It only compiles when storing the result of fetch_values in `result` before returning it. When writing `return fetch_values<T...>()` the compilation fails with `no viable conversion from returned value of type tuple<T, T> to function return type tuple<T&, T&>`. Why does this workaround work?
- Is this valid to do in the first place? Does `result` live long enough until after the values are stored in the `std::tie`'d variables?

[Example showing the issue](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1UrhNL0sus9BBrOp)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I doubt that the values returned from `fetch_values` should then be wrapped in references and returned, but I can't say for sure without having a prototypical implementation of `fetch_values`

Comment: @AndyG This is a very simplified example but it shows the exact behaviour: https://wandbox.org/permlink/1UrhNL0sus9BBrOp

Comment: After trying the compilation of the example with different compilers, it looks like only clang accepts even the workaround with the storage in `result`; GCC rejects both. Is the conversion actually non-valid and clang accepting it is a mistake on clangs part?

Answer (score 1):

your both snippets returns dangling pointer.

You should simply return by value:

```
// temporary class conversion operator
template<typename... T>
operator std::tuple<T...>() const {
    return fetch_values<T...>(); // returns tuple<T...>
}
```

The conversion with `std::tie` will work.

Comment: fetch_values does not operate with reference type arguments, so it would require `fetch_values<std::remove_reference_t<T>...>();`; Which then also needs to be stored in a result before returning to allow the conversion, same as in my last example. I'll edit and clarify that in the question.

Comment: @Appleshell: `std::tie(a, b) =  std::make_tuple(4, 2);` is valid.

Comment: It's not in this composition. See here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/1UrhNL0sus9BBrOp

Comment: Do you really want to allow at the same time `std::tie(a, b) = get_temporary();` and `std::tie(a) = get_temporary();` ? Would it be simpler to have `std::tie(a, b) = get_temporary().get<int, int>();` ?

Comment: Yes, the goal of the temporary is to defer which values to fetch from the assignment implicitly. The only part missing is to make it able to work with std::tie, and I was wondering why the stated workaround worked. Methods with explicit template arguments are already in place.